# PyCharm line completion

Tags: vim, pycharm

I'm currently considering switching from vim to PyCharm and one thing I miss is line completion.

In vim to complete a line you can use: CTRL+X+L. Is this possible in PyCharm

IdeaVim plugin doesn't have this functionality.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Line completion is a common feature of command line interpreters*. Pycharm is a Python and Django IDE with refactorings, **code completion** (for keywords, classes, variables, etc. as you type or via *Ctrl-Space*. ), on-the-fly code analysis and coding.

I think that PyCharm **doesn't** have **line completion**.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not what I asked. I'm looking for a specific type of completion: Line Completion

Comment: Doesn't seem to understand the question.